# how to use or statement in xsl:apply-templates select attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I want to match two expression using OR statement in xsl:apply-templates select.i want to check following conditions...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//w:body/w:p[w:r[w:t]] or //w:body/w:p[w:r[w:pict]]">

 // My Functionality

</xsl:apply-templates>
```

But i dont know how i do this. Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: sorry I added incorrect answer, this is correct usage of "or" (select attribute allows any xPath expression), what you going to achieve with the condition? and what is the problem?

Comment: You were in the correct line using `or`. See my answer. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about XSLT 2.0, but in XSLT 1.0 `<xsl:apply-templates select="//w:body/w:p[w:r[w:t]] or //w:body/w:p[w:r[w:pict]]">` isn't valid query. Use `|` instead of `or`.

Comment: As you can read from my answer, there are better ways to achieve the wanted result, even if what you have shown is not incorrect.

Comment: @empo, I only answered the question, no more... :-)

Comment: In XPath 2.0 you would like write this as `//w:body/(w:p[w:r/w:t] | w:p[w:r/w:t])`, even if still unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `or`, and it's really correct to use it in this context because you don't want the testing nodes:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="
  //w:body
    /w:p
    [w:r/w:t or w:r/w:pict]">
```

---

`|` (*union*) is indispensabile only **if you need to select the testing nodes** (`w:t` and `w:pict`):

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="
  //w:body/w:p/w:r/w:t
  |
  //w:body/w:p/w:r/w:pict">
```

where XPath 2.0 allows you to write more concisely:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="
  //w:body/w:p/w:r/(w:t|w:pict)"/>
```

Comment: I think 1st and 2nd queries aren't equals, or I maybe mistaken?

Comment: Yes. They are really different. I thought I was clear in that. The first select `w:p` the second select the test nodes. Read carefully my words ;-)

Comment: However, it's a matter of taste to use `//w:body/w:p[w:r[w:t]] | //w:body/w:p[w:r[w:pict]]` or `//w:body/w:p[w:r/w:t or w:r/w:pict]`

Comment: Anyway, `//w:body/w:p[w:r/w:t or w:r/w:pict]` is more readable.

Comment: Definitely, if it's a matter of taste (or performance) I would choose this anyway :))