# XPath: logical OR

Tags: c#, xpath, logical-operators

Please help to use the logical OR operator in XPATH and select one request from these two:

1) `.//span[@class=\'fob12\']`

2) `.//p[@class=\'fob12\']`

They differ in *tag* only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One more (with the OR as requested):

```
".//*[(self::p or self::span) and @class = 'fob12']"
```

Comment: [dejavu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854986/how-to-use-or-statement-in-xslapply-templates-select-attribute/6856462#6856462)

Answer (score 9):

You want the [union expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-UnionExpr) which is `|`, so the XPath would be:

```
 .//span[@class="fob12"] | .//p[@class="fob12"]
```

Answer (score 4):

I might be missing something, but the following should just work!?

```
.//span[@class=\'fob12\'] | .//p[@class=\'fob12\']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write it as `.//(p|span)[@class='fob12']`. But I think that needs XPath 2.0 IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Another XPath:

```
.//*[(self::p | self::span)[@class = 'fob12']]
```